# Re-request fb-dialog if User denies scope - Identityserver4

Tags: asp.net-core, facebook-login, identityserver4

Facebook docs give this javascript code

```
FB.login(
  function(response) {
     console.log(response);
},
{
    scope: 'email',
    auth_type: 'rerequest'
});
```

Is it possible to implement above functionality in my StartUp.cs instead?

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Facebook",
    DisplayName = "Facebook",
    SignInScheme = 
                IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme, 
    AppId = "***",
    AppSecret = "***",

    Events = new OAuthEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I was having the same question and maybe my solution will help others in future.

First: To force the consent page at facebook you need to add `auth_type=rerequest` to the query ([handling revoked permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#handling)).

Second: A single revoked permission will not raise an error. It will go the normal way but without the requested scope/claims. So `OnRemoteFailure` will not be called in this case. `OnRemoteFailure` will only be called if the consent page is canceled by the user at all.

Now you can do this:

1. Check the returned claims at [callback method](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/004937b68c8c70b2cf65b58f4ebec59fb056be61/Quickstarts/7_JavaScriptClient/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L175).
2. If the email claim is missing (or any other requested claim that is important for you) redirect the user to a custom page that handles this case. Technically you could redirect the user direct back to facebook but this is not recommended. Facebook expects from you that you explain the user exactly why you need the requested scope ([handling revoked permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking#handling)).
3. Customize the [method that initiates the sign-in process](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/004937b68c8c70b2cf65b58f4ebec59fb056be61/Quickstarts/7_JavaScriptClient/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L148) so that you know when to add auth_type=rerequest, i.e. when the user in step 2) pressed a button like "try again".
4. Add `auth_type=rerequest` to `AuthenticationProperties`

   ```
       var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
       {
           RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback"),
           Items =
               {
                   { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                   { "scheme", provider },
                   // if user wants to try again
                   { "auth_type", "rerequest" }
               }
       };
       return Challenge(props, provider);
   ```
5. Implement `OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint` to manipulate the default challenge redirect uri

   ```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
   ...
   options.Events = new OAuthEvents
   {
       OnRemoteFailure = ...
       OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
       {
           if (context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey("auth_type"))
           {
               context.RedirectUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(context.RedirectUri, "auth_type", context.Properties.Items["auth_type"]);
           }
           context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
           return Task.FromResult(0);
       }
   };
   ```

Now the consent page shows up again when needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I ask why you push the redirect there, and not just modifying the RedirectUri property? I had to do the redirect as well for it to work, but I was wondering if you knew why it was needed. I cant find any information about it, though all examples in internet do it like that.